# Add header #ifndef into C header files in current directory

Tags: python, c, shell, c-preprocessor

In current directory, All C header files (*.h) don't include the preprocessor macro

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
...
#endif
```

, it's too tedious to add them in each header manually. How to do that automatically via python or shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to second @kaylum's advice and also not give you the whole thing, but here is some pseudocode that might set you on the right path

```
for each file in the directory
   if filename doesn't end with .h
      continue
   open the file
   store its contents in a variable
   create the header guard by taking the filename, removing the '.', and replacing it with a '_'
   create new contents = headerGuard + contents + "\n#endif"
   write file back out to the same name
```

Each of these things should be answerable with a quick google/stack overflow search, and if you can't figure out any of those parts, a specific stack overflow question about that bit would be better suited for this site.  [And here is one link to a relevant question to get you started.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Cody's answer, I implemented the guardHeader.py:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python3
  2
  3 import glob,os,sys
  4
  5 global search_dir
  6
  7 def clearContent(pfile):
  8     pfile.seek(0)
  9     pfile.truncate()
 10
 11 def guard(fileName):
 12     file = open(fileName, 'r+')
 13     content = file.read()
 14
 15     fileNameUp = fileName.split(".")[0].upper() + '_H'
 16     guardBegin = '#ifndef ' + fileNameUp + '\n'    \
 17             '#define ' + fileNameUp + '\n\n'
 18     guardEnd = '\n#endif'
 19     newContent = guardBegin + content + guardEnd
 20
 21     clearContent(file)
 22     file.write(newContent)
 23
 24 if __name__ == '__main__':
 25     if len(sys.argv) == 1:
 26         print('Please provide a directory')
 27     else:
 28         search_dir = sys.argv[1]
 29
 30     # enter search directory
 31     os.chdir(search_dir)
 32
 33     for file in glob.glob("*.h"):
 34         guard(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in a `unix`  shell with `find`, `cut`, and `sed` available. You can get each filename using `find`, then use `sed` to change those files.

You can save the below script in a file called `addifndef.sh`.

```
  for fn in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*\.h$' | cut -f 2 -d '/'); 
  do 
     dn=$(echo $fn | cut -f 1 -d '.');
     sed -i  -e "1 i#ifndef ${dn}_H\n#define ${dn}_H" -e "$ a#endif" "$fn";  
  done
```

And, run that script as `[prompt $] sh addifndef.sh` in your shell prompt.

Alternatively you can directly use this command in command line.

For more info you have to look at `man pages` of `find`, `cut`, and `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a small script that gets the job done: https://gist.github.com/rumpeltux/9e4a3e6e8ccd4c0c86770ca4f2afc1d0

```sh
wget https://gist.github.com/rumpeltux/9e4a3e6e8ccd4c0c86770ca4f2afc1d0/raw/auto_add_headers.sh

find -name \*.h | xargs sh auto_add_headers.sh
```